# Router Not Finding Controller Beego

Tags: model-view-controller, go, beego

I had a beego application that was working, and then my router stopped finding the controller, and I have no idea why. No matter what url I type, the router does not direct to the controller complaining nomatch

> 2016/07/26 17:24:50 [router.go:829][D] | GET        | /                                        | 478.352µs        | notmatch   |

**app.conf**

```
appname = exampleapp 
httpport = 8080 
runmode = dev
```

**router.go**

```
package routers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "example/controllers"
```

)

```
func init() {
     beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})
}
```

**default.go (controller)**

```
package controllers

import (
        "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type MainController struct {
        beego.Controller
}

 func (c *MainController) Get() {
        c.Data["Website"] = "http://localhost:8080"
        c.TplName = "index.tpl"
 }
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Pritnln("Starting Beego App")
        beego.Run()
        fmt.Println("Finished Running Beego App")
}
```

I believe this is following the specifications of  http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/router.md so I would like to understand why it does not find the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not importing `routers` package. If you don't import `routers` in anywhere, the `init` function will never be executed. You can test it adding a simple `fmt.Println('I'm initialized')` in `routers.init` function.

```
func init() {
     fmt.Println('I'm initialized')
     beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})
}
```

Ok, you must add a new import with `_` to say that you won't use, but, the `init` function will be executed! Then you must write this in main package:

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/astaxie/beego"

        _ "example/routers"
)
```

I hope that it is useful! :-)

Comment: That was it. Very helpful and a stupid miss on my end. I ended up looking in all the wrong places!